# Restructuring the code vs using APC

Tags: php, apc

I have a PHP web application with a single init.php files having all the methods in it.

It is a huge file with numerous methods. Some pages use it just for calling mysql.

I was planning on restructuring my application as suggested in another question I asked the other day. I read about how APC works and it seemed to me that the code caching might actually work better with my current application structure if I setup APC.

Would it be a good option to go with?

Comment: Why not do both? A good structure and APC aren't incompatible

Comment: A good structure would require me to invest time in it I can use right now for adding new features. But yeah, they aren't incompatible.

Comment: Try APC, see what you get out of it, then decide. Chances are it will not solve your problem out of the box if you have an important bottleneck though.

Comment: Caching opcodes for a huge file is definitely bang for the buck.

Comment: @Jack: What does that even mean?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It means that the benefit of caching opcodes for a huge file gives an appreciable performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it worthwhile investigating what APC offers to help inform your decision.

You could want it to cache op-codes or using it to cache rendered HTML (preventing code being run for each page view).

Mark Bakers advice is sage though, caching sounds like a stop-gap answer but will buy you some time at least.

http://devzone.zend.com/1812/using-apc-with-php/